# Comment analyser « Honteuse de son échec, elle […] » ?

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe

Pourriez-vous m'aider à analyser cette phrase :

> Honteuse de son échec, elle n’ose plus se montrer.

*elle* - sujet

*n'ose plus* - verbe

*se montrer* - COD

Et maintenant, est-ce que *honteuse de son échec* est un complément circonstanciel de cause ou est-ce que *honteuse* est épithète et *de son échec* est un complément déterminatif de *honteuse* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il y a d'autres possibilités  de formulation de cela, lesquelles, du point de vue sens, sont entièrement équivalentes ou **presque**;

1. *simple coordination* _ Elle est honteuse de son échec et (elle) n'ose plus se montrer.
2. *proposition participiale* _   Étant honteuse de son échec, elle n'ose plus se montrer.
3. *subordonnée exprimant la cause explicitement* _  Comme  elle est honteuse de son échec, elle n'ose plus se montrer.
   Parce qu' elle est honteuse de son échec, elle n'ose plus se montrer.
4. *subordonnée avec ellipse du verbe* Parce que honteuse de son échec, elle n'ose plus se montrer.
5. *tournure idiomatique (littéraire)* _ Honteuse qu'elle est de son échec, elle n'ose plus se montrer.
6. *adjectif apposé à « elle »* _ Honteuse de son échec, elle n'ose plus se montrer.

Dans tous les cas sauf le premier et le dernier il est justifié de considérer la forme équivalente comme ayant la fonction de **complément circonstanciel de cause**. L'analyse du syntagme « honteuse de son échec », c'est à dire de ce groupe adjectival, n'a rien à voir avec le reste de la phrase, elle en est indépendante. Du point de vue de sa fonction dans une phrase le groupe adjectival n'est pas autre chose qu'un adjectif écrit en un seul mot : il peut avoir toutes les fonctions de l'adjectif (attribut, épithète, apposé).

- Ses joues étaient *rouges de honte*. (attribut)
- On pouvait voir ses joues *rouges de honte* mais elle restait déterminée. (épithète)
- Honteuse, elle bredouillait. (apposé)

En conclusion, dans la phrase n° 6,

- « honteuse de son échec »  **n'est pas  un complément circonstanciel de cause du verbe « se montrer »** et
- « de son échec » est bien un complément déterminatif de « honteuse » (complément prépositionnel) et
- « **honteuse » n'est pas épithète de « échec** ».

Comme l'exemple le montre, l'épithète se trouve dans un groupe nominal, il modifie un nom, que l'on appelle le **noyau** du groupe; le mot central dans le syntagme adjectival, c'est l'adjectif (honteuse) ; on modifie l'adjectif au moyen d'adverbes ou de locutions adverbiales ; si on avait eu la construction suivante,

- « honteuse **à** ne penser qu'à se cacher »,

on aurait encore un modificateur de l'adjectif en la locution adverbiale « à ne penser qu'à se cacher ».

La fonction d'apposition éclipse la notion de cause : on peut supposer que la cause réside en ce qu'exprime le syntagme, mais on ne peut pas l'affirmer, tout ce que l'on peut considérer c'est qu'il y a une juxtaposition, « honte/ne pas se montrer ». Il n'est donc pas question de considérer la fonction de « honteuse… » en tant que complément circonstanciel mais seulement en tant que  « **syntagme adjectival apposé** ».

Comment: OK, je comprends que ce n'est pas un CC. Je ne pense pas que *honteuse* soit épithète de *échec*, mais de *elle*. Est-ce que c'est possible ?

Comment: Je ne suis pas très calé sur ces questions, mais voici une assertion tirée de la Wikipédia qui laisse peu de doute : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjectif#Adjectif_apposé L'adjectif apposé est séparé par une virgule du groupe nominal ou du pronom auquel il se rapporte : il constitue une expansion détachée du groupe nominal (ex: Émue, elle s'arrêta de parler.).